# Confusing differences in extended ASCII descriptions: block vs U

Tags: unicode, extended-ascii

Sometimes we see extended ascii 219 described as a `block` [https://coding.tools/ascii-table]

sometimes we see it as `Latin capital letter U with circumflex` [https://www.ascii-code.com/]

i cant seem to find details on why this is different sometimes? any insight is appreciated. thank you so much.

Comment: look at the unicode tables instead. dos used its extended char set to make ui elements

Comment: hi dan thanks for replying. i am trying to render the dos ascii extended characters reliably in browsers. i seem to keep getting the latin U.

Comment: you'll have to use a font for that.

Comment: great idea! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a single encoding that "*extended ASCII*" refers to. It just refers generally to encodings which are extensions of ASCII.

For example in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and [ISO-8859-1 ("latin1")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) the value 219 is unicode code point 219 `Û` (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX).

But e.g. in [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) the value 219 is unicode code point 0x2588 `█` (FULL BLOCK).